# conditional iteritems just processes no result/no error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to "loop" this dataframe and add a column based on the condition of another columns.  i think i achieve my result with this logic but cant seem to find the right iterator or other method to create my new column. In this example I am using the **iteritems** but this code just spins for minutes and no result is given,i manually cancel the code. my dataframe has 400,000 columns. a screenshot of df is included.

the goal is to fill the instances where ['close'] == ['prev'] and replace the 0 value with most recent trade signal (either +, or -).

```
for index, col in df.T.iteritems():
  if col['Close'] > col['prev']:
    col['trade2'] = '+'
    x = '+'
    continue
  elif col['Close'] < col['prev']:
    col['trade2'] = '-'
    x = '-'
    continue
  elif col['Close'] == col['prev']:
    col['trade2'] = x
```

[image]

Comment: df.trade.mask(df.trade=='0').ffill()

Comment: @WeNYoBen thanks but this just creates a duplicate of the original 'trade' column.  was this supposed to 'fill down' the value above the zeros?  that idea would work but this doesnt accomplish that... is you notice my screenshot it shows zero values takes the previous (+, or -) signal and fills it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the test DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 36.50, 36.53, '-' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.50, '+' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ],
    [ 36.51, 36.53, '-' ],
    [ 36.51, 36.51, '0' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.51, '+' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ],
    [ 36.53, 36.53, '0' ]],
    columns=['Close', 'prev', 'trade'],
    index=range(5,16))
```

To compute *trade2* value for the current row, we have
to define the following function:

```
def cmp(row):
    global lastResult
    if row.Close > row.prev:
        lastResult = '+'
    elif row.Close < row.prev:
        lastResult = '-'
    return lastResult
```

It uses a global variable *lastResult*, which will be initially set
to *'0'*.

And instead of your loop with *iteritems*, you should just **apply** this
function to each row and substitute the result to the new column,
starting from initial setting of *lastResult* (as mentioned above):

```
lastResult = '0'
df['trade2'] = df.apply(cmp, axis=1)
```

This is just the way how operations of such type should be performed.

And one remark concerning your code.
If you use *iteritems*, then:

- within the loop you should add results to some list,
- **after the loop**, this list should be substituted to a new column.

## Another, quicker solution

If you already have *trade* column, you can execute:

```
df['trade2'] = df.trade.replace(to_replace='0')
```

This method relies on the fact that *trade* column is always a *string*
(either a minus, a plus or '0'), so *to_replace* argument will match (string) zero cases.

The next argument - *value* - has not been given, so it defaults to
*None*.

In such circumstances, the *pad* replace method is assumed, meaning
*fill values forward*.

This way, either '+' or '-' is "replicated" down the column, giving just
the same result.

For source DataFrame with 1100 rows (your DataFrame replicated 100 times)
I got the execution time over 100 times shorter than with the first
method.

Comment: thanks for creating the df for users... but your result duplicates the original 'trade' column. the goal is to fill the zero values with the trade signal (+, -) that is above it. if you notice the screenshot in my original post, it shows what 'trade2' column should look like..

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I corrected the program. Apparently, initially I read your question "too quick" and missed some details. Now it should be OK.

Comment: thank you! that worked.... BUT my only issue is that for the 400,000K rows... this is quite slow, literally like 20 seconds to accomplish.  is there a better method of running this against the rows in dataframe to make it faster?

Comment: thanks for the follow up!  that worked incredible well, maybe 1 seconds on 485,000 rows!